# String splitting based on unknown delimeters (rather, LENGTH of delimeter)

Tags: string, lua

I have a somewhat esoteric problem. My program wants to decode morse code.

The point is, I will need to handle *any* character. Any random characters that adhere to my system and can correspond to a letter should be accepted. Meaning, the letter "Q" is represented by "- - . -", but my program will treat any string of characters (separated by appropriate newchar signal) to be accepted as Q, for example "dj ir j kw" (long long short long).

There is a danger of falling out of sync, so I will need to implement a "new character" signal. I chose this to be "xxxx" as in 4 letters. For white, blank space symbol, I chose "xxxxxx", 6 chars.

Long story short, how can I split the string that is to be decoded into readable characters based on the *length* of the delimeter (4 continous symbols), since I can't really deterministically know *what* letters will make up the newchar delimeter?

Comment: "*for example "dj ir j kw" (long long short long).*" Why is that "long long short long"? Because of the number of characters in the "words"?

Comment: Exactly. I cant control which letters will make up the "words", only the length of the words.

Comment: How is this question related to Lua?

Comment: Thanks for all input. I worked around the problem since the letters themselves can be arbitrary, i just converted every symbol in the string to 0, and then splitted the string into the "words" to decode by using 0000 as the delimeter. It helps to clear your thoughts just by writing it out and reading other's ideas.

Answer (score 1):

The question is not very clearly worded.

For instance, here you show space as a delimeter between parts of the symbol Q:

> for example "dj ir j kw" (long long short long)

Later you say:

> For white, blank space symbol, I chose "xxxxxx", 6 chars.

Is that the symbol for whitespace, or the delimeter you use within a symbol (such as Q, above)? Your post doesn't say.

In this case, as always, an example is worth a thousands words. You should have shown a few examples of possible input and shown how you'd like them parsed.

If what you mean was that "dj ir j kw jfkl abpzoq jfkl dj ir j kw" should be decoded as "Q Q", and you just want to know how to match tokens by their length, then... the question is easy. There's a million ways you could do that.

In Lua, I'd do it in two passes. First, convert the message into a string containing only the length of each chunk of consequitive characters:

```
message = 'dj ir j kw jfkl abpzoq jfkl dj ir j kw'

message = message:gsub('(%S+)%s*', function(s) return #s end)

print(message) --> 22124642212
```

Then split on the number 4 to get each group

```
for group in message:gmatch('[^4]+') do
    print(group)
end
```

Which gives you:

```
2212
6
2212
```

So you could convert something like this:

```
function translate(message)
    local lengthToLetter = {
        ['2212'] = 'Q',
        [   '6'] = ' ',
    }
    local translation = {}
    message = message:gsub('(%S+)%s*', function(s) return #s end)
    for group in message:gmatch('[^4]+') do
        table.insert(translation, lengthToLetter[group] or '?')
    end
    return table.concat(translation)
end

print(translate(message))
```

Answer (score 0):

This will split a string by any `len` continuous occurrences of `char`, which may be a character or pattern character class (such as `%s`), or of any character (i.e. `.`) if `char` is not passed.

It does this by using backreferences in the pattern passed to string.find, e.g. `(.)%1%1%1` to match any character repeated four times.

The rest is just a bog-standard string splitter; the only real Lua peculiarity here is the choice of pattern.

```
-- split str, using (char * len) as the delimiter
-- leave char blank to split on len repetitions of any character
local function splitter(str, len, char)
  -- build pattern to match len continuous occurrences of char
  -- "(x)%1%1%1%1" would match "xxxxx" etc.
  local delim = "("..(char or ".")..")" .. string.rep("%1", len-1)
  local pos, out = 1, {}
  -- loop through the string, find the pattern,
  -- and string.sub the rest of the string into a table
  while true do
    local m1, m2 = string.find(str, delim, pos)
    -- no sign of the delimiter; add the rest of the string and bail
    if not m1 then 
      out[#out+1] = string.sub(str, pos)
      break
    end
    out[#out+1] = string.sub(str, pos, m1-1)
    pos = m2+1
    -- string ends with the delimiter; bail
    if m2 == #str then
      break
    end
  end
  return out
end

-- and the result?
print(unpack(splitter("dfdsfsdfXXXXXsfsdfXXXXXsfsdfsdfsdf", 5)))
-- dfdsfsdf, sfsdf, sfsdfsdfsdf
```